# Folder that is not hidden does not appear in `ls`, autocomplete or Finder

Tags: macos, ls

I have a folder `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` that does not appear at all in `ls`, autocomplete or Finder. If I navigate to the directory in the terminal and use `open .`, Finder opens up to the `Library` folder.  I have "show hidden files" on.

Picture showing command prompt and Finder, showing that Finder has hidden folders available, that the folder can be navigated to in the terminal, and that the folder appears to be missing in Finder

[image]

I can move all its contents into a new folder with `mv minecraft/ minecraft-backup`, and the new folder is completely visible. When I rename the new folder back to `minecraft` it disappears once again. If I make a new folder at `minecraft` it also disappears. If I put a text file in its place, it is also hidden, though can be edited by vim.

Here is the output from running `stat` on the two folders:

```sh
    ⚡︎ stat minecraft/ minecraft-backup/
16777230 32605568 drwxr-xr-x 2 corms staff 0 64 "Dec  4 10:23:58 2021" "Dec  4 10:23:58 2021" "Dec  4 10:23:58 2021" "Dec  4 10:23:58 2021" 4096 0 0 minecraft/
16777230 6291018 drwxr-xr-x 37 corms staff 0 1184 "Dec  4 09:46:29 2021" "Dec  3 21:04:18 2021" "Dec  4 09:57:51 2021" "Jun 20 19:07:15 2020" 4096 0 0 minecraft-backup/
```

Comment: Try `open "./Library/Application Support/minecraft/"` If it's `hidden` by `chflags` then you need to `nohidden` it - which minecraft might fight you on. I don't have minecraft to test.

Comment: What does `ls -leO@d ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` show? (It'll list ACL entries, flags, and extended attributes along with the usual info.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson: `ls: /Users/corms/Library/Application Support/minecraft: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

The post
[I don't have a Minecraft folder anywhere on my Mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294910/i-dont-have-a-minecraft-folder-anywhere-on-my-mac)
contains various methods for unhiding the folder or for positioning
into it.

The easy way that is listed, although not permanent, is to:

> Open Minecraft and launch the game. Click **Options…**, **Resource
> Packs…**, then at the bottom of this screen, find and click **Open
> Resource Pack Folder**.
>
> You will now have a finder window open that is *inside* your
> **minecraft** folder. Navigate up one folder by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and you will be looking at your **minecraft**
> folder.

Comment: This is how I initially determined that I cannot navigate to the folder in Finder. I had clicked it and it opened to `~/Library` instead

Comment: Try the other methods, perhaps one of them will work.